# Why doesn't Postfix deliver from local accounts to local accounts?

Tags: postfix, configuration

I have postfix installed on a machine named `smtp.mydomain.com` with a a virtual domain of `mydomain.com`. If any email arrives at `smtp.mydomain.com` for a local user on that machine from an *external* SMTP server then it gets delivered locally as expected.

However if `user1@mydomain.com` sends to `user2@mydomain.com` using `smtp.mydomain.com` then the email is not delivered locally to user2 as expected but instead is relayed to the catch all alias `someone@otherdomain.com` for the domain mydomain.com.

So basically local user to local user using the Postfix machine does not work. Any suggestions on how I fix or diagnose this? It has to be something really obvious.

I post my config here in case it helps:

`postconf -n`:

```
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
myhostname = smtp.mydomain.com
myorigin = mydomain.com
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023 reject_unknown_reverse_client_hostname
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/tls/certs/smtp.mydomain.com.cert
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/tls/private/smtp.mydomain.com.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:/var/spool/postfix/smtpd_tls_cache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
smtpd_use_tls = no
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

`cat /etc/postfix/virtual`:

```
mydomain.com  mydomain.com
@mydomain.com someone@otherdomain.com
user1@mydomain.com       user1.mydomain.com
user2@mydomain.com     user2.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the line `@mydomain.com someone@otherdomain.com` to the end of the file. That's all.

Oh and I see it now: There should be `@`s in the destination addresses. So your file should look like this:

```
mydomain.com    mydomain.com
user1@mydomain.com    user1@mydomain.com
user2@mydomain.com    user2@mydomain.com
@mydomain.com    someone@otherdomain.com
```

Comment: Moved "@mydomain.com someone@otherdomain.com" to the end of the line and then ran postmap /etc/postfix/virtual and restarted postfix. Still has the same behaviour.

Also the second column user1.mydomain is supposed to represent a local user account so the @ is not required?

Suffice to say I still have the same unwanted behaviour originally described.

Comment: You have to name the user in "full-qualified" form. Or where are your `virtual_mailbox_maps` with these user-mailbox mappings?